# When creating an invoice on xero I get the error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am creating invoices on Xero but a couple of times (maybe 3 or 4 in about 1000 calls) i get the error: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

*NOTE - the invoice is still being created*

Here's the code where im getting the error:

```js
    const invoices = {
      invoices: [invoice],
    };

    let invoiceData: { body: Invoices } | undefined;
    try {
      invoiceData = await this.xero?.accountingApi.createInvoices(
        this.getTenantId(),
        invoices,
        true,
        4,
      );
    } catch (error: any) {
      const errors = error?.response?.body?.Elements?.[0]?.ValidationErrors;
      throw errors;
    }

    const invoiceNumber = invoiceData?.body?.invoices?.[0]?.invoiceNumber;
```